# Get two columns from 2D array and insert into a fun to use the array

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I have a function is to draw polygon with Cesium. And for the `hierarchy : new Cesium.PolygonHierarchy(Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([])` I want put a data from a CSV file. and the CSV file has 6 columns. I just want to use 3rd and 4th columns to instead of

```
-120.03, 30.464,
-120.43, 30.779,
-120.85, 31.12,
```

so, how do I do that?

```
<script id="cesium_sandcastle_script">
    function startup(Cesium) {
        'use strict';

        //Sandcastle_Begin
        Cesium.Math.setRandomNumberSeed(1234);

        var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', { infoBox : false });
        var entities = viewer.entities;

        entities.add({
            polygon : {
                hierarchy : new Cesium.PolygonHierarchy(Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([
                    -120.03, 30.464,
                    -120.43, 30.779,
                    -120.85, 31.12,
                ])),

                extrudedHeight : 99900.0,
                outline : true,
                outlineColor : Cesium.Color.WHITE,
                outlineWidth : 4,
                material : Cesium.Color.fromRandom({alpha : 0.5})
            }
        });
```

`code`
This is the data from csv

ID,Index,Latitude,Longitude,Floor,Ceiling
No1,0,30.464,-120.03,0,99900
No1,1,30.779,-120.43,0,99900
No1,2,31.12,-120.85,0,99900
No1,3,31.477999999999998,-121.28,0,99900
No1,4,31.846999999999998,-121.71000000000001,0,99900
No1,5,32.418,-122.36999999999999,0,99900
No1,6,32.905,-121.74,0,99900

Comment: We'll need to see an example of the data your are receiving from the CSV file...

Comment: `code`
ID,Index,Latitude,Longitude,Floor,Ceiling
No1,0,30.464,-120.03,0,99900
No1,1,30.779,-120.43,0,99900
No1,2,31.12,-120.85,0,99900
No1,3,31.477999999999998,-121.28,0,99900
No1,4,31.846999999999998,-121.71000000000001,0,99900
No1,5,32.418,-122.36999999999999,0,99900
No1,6,32.905,-121.74,0,99900

Comment: this is the data

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put the data in there.